# Odoo 10 - Qweb PDF report header_spacing and margin_top properties

Tags: odoo-10, odoo, qweb

I am defining my own `report.paperformat`. I am trying differnet configurations for `margin_top` and `header_space` but I can not manage to undersand what does each parameter.

- When a given value is used in`margin_top` and `header_space`, which are the units being used by `wlkhtmltopdf`?
- What are exactly each value?
- A value of `15` in `margin_top` and a value of `5` is used in `header_line`, what does that mean?

Comment: Refer this official doc of odoo: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/reports.html

This may help you.

Comment: Official docs are poor in this specific case: `header_spacing` definition at official docs is `header spacing in mm` and `margin_top` description is `margin sizes in mm`. I expect a definition not to include the term to be defined, or at least not JUST include the term to be defined..

Answer (score 7):

Please see below image.

[image: Odoo Qweb Margin]

if you increase the Header spacing you also need to adjust the top margin as well. above image was using

- Top Margin (mm) = 40.00
- Header Spacing = 35.00

hope this helps to understand **Top Margin** and **Header Spacing** parameter!

Comment: That is what I was expecting from `header_spacing` and `margin_top`, but my tests give different results. According to your statement, changing header spacing shall not alter at all header, and in the tests I have done it does.

Answer (score 1):

For more add this to your report.

```
<record id="paperformat_sales" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">A4 Sale Order</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True" />
    <field name="format">A4</field>
    <field name="page_height">0</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
    <field name="margin_top">8</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">0</field>
    <field name="margin_left">3</field>
    <field name="margin_right">0</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False" />
    <field name="header_spacing">5</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
</record>

<record id="action_sale_order" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="your_module_name.paperformat_sales"/>
</record>
```